# Missing '+' to create a new task on salesforce 1 app. It is available for other objects

Tags: salesforce1-app

[image][image]When i am opening open Acitivities in salesforce1 app, am unable to see '+' symbol to create new task. I am able to create a task from task tab. But this is not available in the related list only.

I am able to see this option for the other objects in the related lists.

Please suggest an idea, how to enable this option.

Thank you.

Comment: There should be a "button" or "bar" at the very top of the app that says "New Task" when in Tasks which I suspect has been relabeled as Activities by your Admin. If this is not the case, please edit your post to show us a screen capture and tell us what OS you're using.

Comment: Please look in to the screen shot, i am a system administrator. Still i am unable to see either '+' or New task button. please advice.

Comment: I see the back button. Are you looking at the Accounts related list for Activities? If so, you can click on any Activity and you'll get a menu that will appear at the bottom which will show the New Task icon in it. The Related list itself doesn't appear to have an Add New Task Icon or button.

Comment: I have opened an activity, still option for creating a new task isn't available. I have updated the screen shot..please take a look

Comment: Have you clicked on the 3 dots to see the other options? Once you do, it should appear as one of the icons. Only so many can be displayed at once. It's not one of the 1st to appear.  Apologies for not being clear about that.

Comment: In the 3 dots aso there is no option to create a task, there is an option to follow up the task. please advice.

Answer (score 0):

In Setup, If you go to Create>GlobalActions>GlobalActions, you should see something that looks like below which included `NewTask`:

[image: Global Actions List]

If you then go to Create>GlobalActions>PublisherLayouts, highlight "Salesforce1 and Lightning Actions" you should see something that looks like what's below:

[image: Global Layouts Editor]

In the lower section under **Salesforce 1 and Lightning Experience Actions**, click on the blue link where it says "customize predefined actions". You'll then see a screen like this one:

[image]

Notice that mine shows `NewTask` as one of the actions. You'll see all of the available actions in the menu at the top of the page. `NewTask` should on the list of available actions as it was in the Main list of Global Actions in the first screen above. If it's not in your list of predefined actions, add it and save. It should then be available to you when you click on an individual `Task` in the related list from `Accounts`.

Here's what it looks like for me on my Samsung S5:

[image: Salesforce1 Screen Capture Samsung S5]

Comment: Followed the same steps stated above, still the same page is getting displayed. Looged out and logged in again..Not sure why this is happening!!

Comment: Trying clearing your cache in SF1 on your device.